# Unable to disable X-axis labels in amcharts v4

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I want to disable/hide all the countries labels in x-axis and worndering how is this possible.

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/BrXwQL

```
chart.data = data;

// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "country";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.title.text = "Units sold (M)";
valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.renderer.baseGrid.disabled = true;
valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeOpacity = 0.07;

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "units";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
```

Comment: I have browsed that. unfortunately my question is similar but also different. Appreciate if it could be solved according to the code /codepen link

Comment: It will also be helpful if the x-axis labels could be written vertically, if hiding completely is not an option

Comment: @Tedinoz - it's not a duplicate. This is for the newest version of AmCharts and the API is completely different. The question should call the fact that it's a new version out a little better for folks that aren't in the know to prevent unnecessary downvotes/flags.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In AmCharts v4, you can remove the labels by disabling them inside the axis renderer's label template:

```
axisObject.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;
```

In this case, replace `axisObject` with the name of the variable holding the desired axis (`categoryAxis`). Demo below

```js
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

var data = [{
 "country": "Lithuania",
 "units": 500,
 "pie": [{
  "value": 250,
  "title": "Cat #1"
 }, {
  "value": 150,
  "title": "Cat #2"
 }, {
  "value": 100,
  "title": "Cat #3"
 }]
}, {
 "country": "Czech Republic",
 "units": 300,
 "pie": [{
  "value": 80,
  "title": "Cat #1"
 }, {
  "value": 130,
  "title": "Cat #2"
 }, {
  "value": 90,
  "title": "Cat #3"
 }]
}, {
 "country": "Ireland",
 "units": 200,
 "pie": [{
  "value": 75,
  "title": "Cat #1"
 }, {
  "value": 55,
  "title": "Cat #2"
 }, {
  "value": 70,
  "title": "Cat #3"
 }]
}];


// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0; // this creates initial fade-in

// Add data
chart.data = data;

// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "country";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.title.text = "Units sold (M)";
valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.renderer.baseGrid.disabled = true;
valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeOpacity = 0.07;

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "units";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";


var columnTemplate = series.columns.template;
// add tooltip on column, not template, so that slices could also have tooltip
columnTemplate.column.tooltipText = "Series: {name}\nCategory: {categoryX}\nValue: {valueY}";
columnTemplate.column.tooltipY = 0;
columnTemplate.column.cornerRadiusTopLeft = 20;
columnTemplate.column.cornerRadiusTopRight = 20;
columnTemplate.strokeOpacity = 0;


// as by default columns of the same series are of the same color, we add adapter which takes colors from chart.colors color set
columnTemplate.adapter.add("fill", (fill, target) => { 
 var color = chart.colors.getIndex(target.dataItem.index * 3);
 return color;
});

// create pie chart as a column child
var pieChart = series.columns.template.createChild(am4charts.PieChart);
pieChart.width = am4core.percent(80);
pieChart.height = am4core.percent(80);
pieChart.align = "center";
pieChart.valign = "middle";
pieChart.dataFields.data = "pie";

var pieSeries = pieChart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
pieSeries.dataFields.value = "value";
pieSeries.dataFields.category = "title";
pieSeries.labels.template.disabled = true;
pieSeries.ticks.template.disabled = true;
pieSeries.slices.template.stroke = am4core.color("#ffffff");
pieSeries.slices.template.strokeWidth = 1;
pieSeries.slices.template.strokeOpacity = 0;

pieSeries.slices.template.adapter.add("fill", (fill, target)=>{
  return am4core.color("#ffffff")
});

pieSeries.slices.template.adapter.add("fillOpacity", (fillOpacity, target)=>{
  return (target.dataItem.index + 1) * 0.2;
});

pieSeries.hiddenState.properties.startAngle = -90;
pieSeries.hiddenState.properties.endAngle = 270;
```

```css
body {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica,
    Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 600px;
  height: 97vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<div id="piechart1" class="asset"></div>
<div id="piechart2" class="asset"></div>
<div id="piechart3" class="asset"></div>
```